# Include quotes around text between square brackets where none exist using regex in DreamWeaver

Tags: php, regex, dreamweaver, regex-negation

I have some php code which picks up variables from a form for example:

`$refno = $_POST[refno];`

This is actually a mistake as refno (a constant) should be 'refno' a string. In older versions of PHP it defaulted to 'refno' without a problem, but the latest versions give a notice to say that it is defaulting, which appears on the screen.

I need to go through all the modules with DreamWeaver and replace:

any occurrence of `[*]`

with `['*']`

but exclude any cases where there are single quotes already.

I have searched through the forum for similar cases without success.

I thought something like this:

`/\[(?!')/x`

to find the square brackets that don't have any quotes, but that doesn't find them.

I am a newby at regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use dreamweaver, but try this:

```
find: \[([^'\]]+)\]
replace: ['$1']
```

Comment: That does the first part. It finds [refno] and replaces it with ['refno'] but when it finds ['first'] it changes it to [''first''] which is not what I wanted. I wanted the latter to be left as it was. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @Geoff: Have you tested it?

Comment: @Casimir_et_Hippolyte Yes I have. As I said it works for text without quotes. It finds the text, and inserts quotes, but if there are quotes already, surrounding the text, it inserts a second pair of quotes. I really wanted it to ignore square brackets with text enclosed in quotes.

Comment: I found it was easiest just to go trough the modules concerned and edit them manually. Also I could turn off reporting of the notices in php.ini for the production system.